# error parsing jsonList to dropdownlist Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, drop-down-menu

I am having issues populating a dropdown list with a JSON List.
Here is what I am doing in my function.

```
onPhaseChange1: function(dropdown, row) {

        var combobox = $(dropdown);
        comboboxWorkUnit = row.find("select.workUnit");
        EmployeeType = $("input[id*='EmployeeType']").val();

        comboboxWorkUnit.show();
        comboboxWorkUnit.empty();

        var jsonList = {
        [{ "Id": "12345", "WorkUnitId": "SR0001954", "Description": "Test Service Request From Serena", "WorkUnitCategory": "ServiceRequest" },
{ "Id": "12355", "WorkUnitId": "WOR001854", "Description": "Test Work Order From Serena", "WorkUnitCategory": "ServiceRequest" },
{ "Id": "12365", "WorkUnitId": "DBR001274", "Description": "Test Database Related Service Request From Serena", "WorkUnitCategory": "ServiceRequest"}]}


$($.parseJSON(jsonList)).map(function() { $('<option>').val(this.Id).text(this.Id).appendTo(comboboxWorkUnit); }); 
    },
```

Comment: $.parseJSON() expects a string.  It looks like you are passing it an object instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jsonList should just be an array.  It doesn't need to be in an object.  Then call each on the array.  fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brentmn/Jkxe2/

```
   var comboboxWorkUnit = $("select.workUnit");

    comboboxWorkUnit.show();
    comboboxWorkUnit.empty();

    var jsonList = [{
        "Id": "12345",
        "WorkUnitId": "SR0001954",
        "Description": "Test Service Request From Serena",
        "WorkUnitCategory": "ServiceRequest"},
    {
        "Id": "12355",
        "WorkUnitId": "WOR001854",
        "Description": "Test Work Order From Serena",
        "WorkUnitCategory": "ServiceRequest"},
    {
        "Id": "12365",
        "WorkUnitId": "DBR001274",
        "Description": "Test Database Related Service Request From Serena",
        "WorkUnitCategory": "ServiceRequest"}];


    $(jsonList).each(function() {
        comboboxWorkUnit.append($('<option>').val(this.Id).text(this.Id));
    });
```

Comment: This looks like a working solution.  However, I would recommend appending the generated options to a string variable while inside the loop, and then performing a single append of that string to the select box.  It will be more efficient than manipulating the DOM multiple times.